# ¿Como parar un ciclo While cuando ya no recibo Bytes por InputStream en Android?

Tags: android, socket, while

estoy creando una aplicación en **Android Studio**, tengo un problema con un ciclo **While** ya que se queda ciclado cuando no recibo nada por **InputStream** de un **Socket**

este es mi código

```
byte[] Length = new byte[2000];
        int bytes=0;
        String dataString = "";
        boolean end=false;



        try
        {

                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.30");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("m");
                DataInputStream stream=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                while(!end){

                    if((bytes=stream.read(Length))!=0){
                        dataString+=new String(Length,0,bytes);
                    }else {
                        end=true;
                    }

                }



                String recibido=dataString;
                Log.d("recibido",recibido);
                prueba(recibido);}
```

en total recibo 96 bytes, el ciclo **While** da 2 vueltas pero a la tercera vuelta se queda ciclado ya que he hecho pruebas con **Log** para ver en que parte se queda ciclado y no me imprime nada, algún método para poder parar el ciclo **While** cuando ya no recibo ningún entero de la variable **bytes**

Comment: Sugiero que revises [este artículo](https://www.baeldung.com/java-inputstream-server-socket), especialmente el apartado **3** y el ejemplo de código que hay en él, que es justo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un [`break;`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html),  que es lo que se usa en Java para terminar la ejecución de un bucle.

Ejemplo:

```
    int counter = 0;
    while(true){
          System.out.println("counter: " + counter);
        if(counter == 10){ //si counter es igual a 10, termina.
            System.out.println("TERMINA!");
            break;
        }

        counter++;

    }
```

salida:

```
counter: 0
counter: 1
counter: 2
counter: 3
counter: 4
counter: 5
counter: 6
counter: 7
counter: 8
counter: 9
counter: 10
TERMINA!
```

---

En el caso de tu código, al terminar la lectura de datos, puedes terminar el bucle, de esta forma:

```
            while(true){

                if((bytes=stream.read(Length))!=0){
                    dataString+=new String(Length,0,bytes);
                }else {
                   break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu tiempo en responderme mi pregunta, mira, lo curioso es que el ciclo solo da 2 vueltas, a la tercera vuelta no se procesa absolutamente nada, ni la condición IF ni nada que ponga antes de esa condición, he puesto un Log para ver si aparece un Log por tercera vez y no es asi, entonces creo que hay algo mas a fondo en el inputStream ya que cicla el while y no avanza ni se detiene